# Ignore single character/letter in a string

Tags: python, string, character

How do you ignore a single character or symbol in a string

I want to ignore the `!` and `/` in `text` or actually just the first character no matter what it was.

For example, something like this:

```
text = ['!kick', '/ban']
```

the output should look like this:

```
>> kick
>> ban
```

instead of:

```
>> !kick
>> /ban
```

Comment: Have you tried any solutions? Also, are you writing an IRC bot? If so, please state in the question. Finally, elaborate more on your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
text = ['!kick', '/ban', '!k!ck']
for s in text:
    print s[0].translate(None, '!/') + s[1:]

output:
kick
ban
k!ck
```

In the second parameter of `translate()` put all of the characters you want to get rid of.

[Read more about `translate()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.translate)

Comment: For future visitors: translate() works way differently in Python3. And Python2 is no longer supported. New link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate

Answer (score 1):

To remove a specific char:

```
s=s.replace("!","") #!4g!hk becomes 4ghk
```

To remove 1st char:

```
s=s[1:]
```

Comment: What do you mean with s=s?

Comment: At time t0, s=='!kick', s[1:]=='kick'\n
At time t1, s=='kick'

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to remove certain characters in the first position of the string, I'd suggest using `str.lstrip()`.

```
for cmd in ['!kick', '/ban']:
    print cmd.lstrip('!/')
```

Answer (score -2):

Just use python's replace function:

```
for elem in ['!kick', '/ban']:
  print elem.replace('!','').replace('/','')
```

Output should look like this:

```
>> kick
>> ban
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the '' in the second replace command.
However, Python's Error message "TypeError: replace() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)" is quite easy to understand, so you could have guessed that yourself